# Adjust slider by textbox value

Tags: slider, dojo

- A demo is there to get the slider value in textbox.
- Is it possible to get the slider adjusted after giving some value into the textbox.
- I should move the slider by textbox value not using mouse.

  the below link has slider value in textbox. vice cersa is possible? if so can i have the code?
  [Programmatic example of a horizontal slider](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/form/HorizontalSlider.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the value of the slider by calling the set method:

```
var slider = new HorizontalSlider(...);
    slider.set('value', 2);
```

Comment: can you check this link please.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15826506/set-dojox-grid-datagrid-header-column-width-dynamically